# SQL Server Patch Fails (SP2\CU4)

Tags: sql-server

I am currently on Windows Server 2012R2, SQL Server 2016 sp2\cu4. On 2/24/19 I attempted to install sp2/cu5, then on 4/27 i attempted to install sp2/cu6... both of these failed. From what I understand about applying sql server patches when I run the package it essentially un-packs all of it's compressed files into directory, runs the install, and then should clean up. But somewhere in the process it fails.

Verified current version by running 'Select @@Version'
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU4) (KB4464106) - 13.0.5233.0 (X64)   Nov  3 2018 00:01:54   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

**Error details:**
 Error installing SQL Server Common Files.The upgrade cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade.
Error code: 1642
Log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190519_063904\MSSQLSERVER\sql_common_core_Cpu64_1.log

Log File Detail:
=== Verbose logging started: 5/19/2019  6:40:02  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.9600.00  Calling process: E:\8537cd18e2054e3b2fece6d5f564\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe ===
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {57846DA8-8B5D-4466-B850-E8CDFC94046C}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Attempting to enable all disabled privileges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:263]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:263]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction {57846DA8-8B5D-4466-B850-E8CDFC94046C}
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:263]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {57846DA8-8B5D-4466-B850-E8CDFC94046C}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\Windows\Installer\inprogressinstallinfo.ipi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: SRSetRestorePoint skipped for this transaction.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: End dialog not enabled
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Original package ==> C:\Windows\Installer\1842ef5.msi
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Package we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\1842ef5.msi
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall Flags override found.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall VersionNT override found.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: APPCOMPAT: Uninstall ServicePackLevel override found.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: APPCOMPAT: looking for appcompat database entry with ProductCode '{57846DA8-8B5D-4466-B850-E8CDFC94046C}'.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: APPCOMPAT: no matching ProductCode found in database.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: File will have security applied from OpCode.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Original patch ==> E:\8537cd18e2054e3b2fece6d5f564\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\sql_common_core.msp
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Patch we're running from ==> C:\Windows\Installer\1025da.msp
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Opening existing patch 'C:\Windows\Installer\89322.msp'.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: SequencePatches starts. Product code: {57846DA8-8B5D-4466-B850-E8CDFC94046C}, Product version: 13.0.1601.5, Upgrade code: {F2F6463E-EE2A-4C0B-B399-F550C887354A}, Product language 1033
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of QFE patch E:\8537cd18e2054e3b2fece6d5f564\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\sql_common_core.msp against product code: 
                                {57846DA8-8B5D-4466-B850-E8CDFC94046C}, product version: 13.0.1601.5, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {F2F6463E-EE2A-4C0B-B399-F550C887354A}
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: PATCH SEQUENCER: QFE patch E:\8537cd18e2054e3b2fece6d5f564\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\sql_common_core.msp is not applicable.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Other Patches:
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Unknown\Absent: {D20E0888-BDCC-40E9-8EA7-3293D389DCC0} - E:\8537cd18e2054e3b2fece6d5f564\x64\setup\sql_common_core_msi\sql_common_core.msp
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Product: SQL Server 2016 Common Files - Update '{D20E0888-BDCC-40E9-8EA7-3293D389DCC0}' could not be installed. Error code 1642. Additional information is available in the log file
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190519_063904\MSSQLSERVER\sql_common_core_Cpu64_1.log.

MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Windows Installer installed an update. Product Name: SQL Server 2016 Common Files. Product Version: 13.0.1601.5. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation.
                                Update Name: {D20E0888-BDCC-40E9-8EA7-3293D389DCC0}. Installation success or error status: 1642.

MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Product: SQL Server 2016 Common Files -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: SQL Server 2016 Common Files. Product Version: 13.0.1601.5. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. 
                                Installation success or error status: 1642.

MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: Attempting to delete file C:\Windows\Installer\1025da.msp
MSI (s) (58:E8) [06:40:02:279]: MainEngineThread is returning 1642
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
The upgrade cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing, or the upgrade may update a different version of the program. Verify that the program to be upgraded exists 
                 on your computer and that you have the correct upgrade.
C:\Windows\Installer\1842ef5.msi
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (58:C8) [06:40:02:279]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:279]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (58:84) [06:40:02:279]: MainEngineThread is returning 1642
=== Verbose logging stopped: 5/19/2019  6:40:02 ===

Comment: Are you sure you have SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU4 installed.  "The upgrade cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded may be missing" indicates you might have something else installed.

Comment: Verified current version by running 'Select @@Version'

 Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU4) (KB4464106) - 13.0.5233.0 (X64) Nov 3 2018 00:01:54 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: not able to add screenshot of instance

Comment: Have you downloaded the [update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56975) and run it as Administrator?

Comment: yes I downloaded patch from link above, ran it as Administrator and it failed. I was able to install windows updates on this server that is failing to successfully install sql server patch sp2/cu4, sp2/cu5, or sp2/cu6 . I also have 3 other server where the patch was installed successfully.

Comment: not really sure what to do at this point I feel like I should uninstall all installed Hotfies under Microsoft SQL Server2016(64-bit). This would be me 4 patches and take me down to build # 13.2.526.0, then attempt to work my way back up to current build# 13.0.5292.0 for sp2/cu6. This server is also part of an AlwaysOn AG with 2 secondary replicas 1 sych/1 asynch and seem to be performing well with other replicas being on sp2/cu6.